# Migration from tsLint to esLint results in Error

Tags: angular, typescript, migration

if i am upgrading to esLint with:  ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
i get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: codelyzer@0.0.28
npm ERR! Found: tslint@6.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!   dev tslint@"~6.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslint@"^3.9.0" from codelyzer@0.0.28
npm ERR! node_modules/codelyzer
npm ERR!   dev codelyzer@"^0.0.28" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: tslint@3.15.1
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!   peer tslint@"^3.9.0" from codelyzer@0.0.28
npm ERR!   node_modules/codelyzer
npm ERR!     dev codelyzer@"^0.0.28" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
```

My package.json looks like:

```
{   "name": "EDUSupport",   "version": "0.0.0",   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.4",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^10.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^15.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "loader-utils": "^3.2.1",
    "material-icons-font": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-avatars": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"   } }
```

Since this try i also get this erro if i remove my node_modules folder and run npm i....

Angular Version is 15.0.4
Global CLI is 15.2.8

If i try upgrading Angular to V16 first i also get the same error. With --legacy-peer-deps i get the nod_modules installed. I also tried to downgrade global CLI remove the all global node modules reinstall them.